# Folders open in new windows when set to use same window

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7: I have the Browse folders option set to "Open each folder in the same window" in the Folder Options dialog. Double-clicking folders opens a new window. Please, make it stop.

Comment: I have discovered that right-clicking and selecting "Open" on the context menu will open the selected folder in the same window. I have no idea why double-clicking and right-clicking would behave differently, but it may be a clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. Re-registering two dll's and rebooting solved it:

```
regsvr32 "%SystemRoot%\System32\actxprxy.dll"
regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"
```

I discovered the solution here: http://www.davidmoore.info/2009/08/19/solution-explorer-open-each-folder-in-same-window-error-and-sql-management-studio-ie-and-team-explorer-errors/

Comment: I saw the linked article last week and have just had a good opportunity to reboot. Thanks.

Be sure to "run as administrator" to do this.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, registering the DLLs mentioned in the accepted answer didn't work. Instead I had to run the System File Checker from a Command Prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem on the machine I'm at, but it doesn't happen on other machines I've used in the past. You inspired me to try something just now

In folder options, choose file types. find the "(NONE) Folder" item and click on Advanced
set the default action to open (was yours set to explore like mine?). That didn't work, but I did notice it's opening up in new window when the folders pane is visible, and otherwise in its own window - does that match your behaviour?

Comment: File Types isn't part of the Windows 7 Folder Options dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

if it is not due to virus then go to folder option, general, browse folders, click on radio button (open each button in same window)... It's for windows 7